# SQL Code to Update Entities with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have an app to manage our Member's information that is tied to a SQL Database. We have attributes that the users can set that apply to the whole family. I am trying to write a SQL Script that will update the values for the whole family.
Example:
Here is a sample of a few columns of our dbo.AttributeValue column:

| AttributeID | EntityID | Value | CreatedDateTime | ModifiedDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5856 | 733 | True | 2021-11-06 17:30:38.207 | 2021-11-10 13:52:09.843 |
| 5856 | 613 | Fale | 2021-11-05 12:12:08.207 | 2021-11-16 3:32:01.843 |

Here is a sample of a few columns in our dbo.Person Table:

| ID | PrimaryFamilyID |
| --- | --- |
| 733 | 187 |
| 709 | 187 |
| 137 | 187 |

I would like for anyone with the same value in PrimaryFamilyID to have the same values in the dbo.AttributeValue table. Bonus points if we can make it update to the value with the most recent ModifiedDateTime in the dbo.AttributeValue table so that if someone in the family modifies the value after every has an assigned attribute, it will go ahead an update those as well.

Desired outcome:

| AttributeID | EntityID | Value | CreatedDateTime | ModifiedDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5856 | 733 | True | 2021-11-06 17:30:38.207 | 2021-11-10 13:52:09.843 |
| 5856 | 709 | True | 2021-11-06 17:30:38.207 | 2021-11-10 13:52:09.843 |
| 5856 | 137 | True | 2021-11-06 17:30:38.207 | 2021-11-10 13:52:09.843 |

Comment: what you want is Select from both table satisfying your given condition Or you want to Update query to update existing table? It is not clear

Comment: Also can you add one more dataset for AttributeValue table so that it is clear for what you want for Most recent Modified scenario

Comment: I've added another row to the attribute value example. I am looking for an update/insert statement. The attribute value for a given Entity ID may or may not be already in the table.

Comment: Since the Entity Id is not present update won't make you achieve the desired result. Making a new table and dumping data based on select seems viable solution to me.

Comment: Is that the same if the EntityID in dbo.AttributeValue =  ID in dbo.Person?

Comment: I agree EntityID in dbo.AttributeValue is same to what is ID in dbo.Person but since 709 and 137 Id's are not present in your EntityId dataset in dbo.AttributeValue. So update on dbo.AttributeValue will not bring those records in desired result set .that's why I suggested insert in new table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to get to a solution what you want is but here it is
[DBFiddleRunningSolution](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pgdEwbbpFXam7zFzjFCNTB/0)
You can start somewhere from here.

```
With PersonCTE as (
Select Count(*)  as cnt,PrimaryFamilyId
from Person 
group by PrimaryFamilyId
having count(*)>1
)
Select AV.AttributeId,P.Id,AV.Value,AV.CreatedDateTime,AV.ModifiedDateTime 
into NewAttributeValue
from Person P inner join PersonCTE C
ON P.PrimaryFamilyId = C.PrimaryFamilyId
cross join AttributeValue AV 
where AV.EntityId in (Select distinct Id from Person)
```